# Mocking delaying process without using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have created an async function that takes about 2 ~ 3 secs to process. I also have a status polling function that checks if the process is done.

I want to validate this whole process on Jest without using setTimeout. Would it be possible on JS?

```js
let isDone = false;

async function longDelaying() {
  // ...
  isDone = true;
}

async function poll() {
  return isDone;
}
```

```js
longDelaying();
poll() // -> false
setTimeout(() => {
  poll() // -> true 
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Why you are using async function when you should wait until that process is done? Why don't you use await function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` to check for its value so many times a second. You can check each time whether the `isDone=true`. And when it is `true` you can clear that `setInterval` function.

It's a dirty trick, though.

The Code for this:

```
var myChecker = setInterval(function() {
    if (isDone){
        .... //some process you want to do
        clearInterval(myChecker); //removes this function
    }
}, 1000); //for checking each 1 second
```